# Ubuntu & Windows 10 - file weirdness on shared fat32 drive

Tags: dual-boot, files, partitioning, sharing

So I don't know where to look for an answer so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I run a dual boot system, with Ubuntu 18.04 on a 32gb msata drive, and Windows 10 in a 64gb partition on a 250gb ssd. The rest of the space on the ssd i formated as Fat32, to have a shared storage space. I use different programs on either OS, and rarely need to share files between the two.

I always hibernate both OS's instead of shutting down.

Now the weirdness...
Yesterday I needed to look at an html file I created in Ubuntu from Windows; Windows began complaining of the file being corrupt. So I ran chkdsk, it 'fixed' the file, and then both OS's could no longer read the file so I lost all the work (grrrrr). So I started testing creating files, and found:

If I create the file in Windows, then hibernate, Ubuntu can read the file no problem. If I create the file in Ubuntu, Windows either does not see it (I can confirm it exists by booting back to Ubuntu) or says it is corrupt.

However if I reboot Windows before looking, Windows sees the file and can open and edit it just fine...

Does anyone know what might be going on? I would rather not shut Windows down everytime, but at the moment that is my solution. I figure this has to be an issue of Windows doing something to the partition, but Ubuntu could be to blame.

Is there any info I can provide to help? Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: It sounds like that Windows does not refresh FAT file system table on a fixed drive.  Because you hibernate and resume, it just has and old inconsistent copy of the file system table.  There's nothing to improve if you insist on hibernation.

Comment: Hmmm, so there is no way to force a refresh?

Comment: You could try unmount the drive before suspend and mount back the drive after resume.  But with all that efforts I don't see why you should bother than just shutdown OS.  And this is actually not Linux related. https://superuser.com/questions/295913/how-to-mount-and-unmount-hard-drives-under-windows-the-unix-way

Comment: Well I would say I am only partly sure this is Windows fault, as at the moment when the drive is mounted in Ubuntu all files and folders are owned by root and marked rwx. Could it be that how I mount it in Ubuntu has some effect?